# Best choice in ARM Cortex series for running RTOS A-,R- or M?

Tags: arm, rtos, cortex

I am learning about ARM Cortex based systems. I understand that most of the Cortex series can support running an OS. When it comes to real time operating systems implementation on an embedded system, such as porting variant of FreeRTOS on a custom embedded board. 
What should be basis of selection of particular ARM Cortex series ?

For running RTOS on ARM Cortex is ARM Cortex-R series the de-facto norm ?

Note: Consider I am going for a hard real time system.

Comment: Debian Linux is not a real time operating system. For hard real time Cortex M, or R would be best.

Answer (score 1):

Cortex-M can be used for hard real-time applications, and tend to cover the lower end of the performance scale (but still a wide range).

Cortex-R are specifically designed for high performance and real-time applications (automotive, storage, modem, etc.)

Cortex-A are designed for running OS like linux, as efficiently as possible or with high performance - so determinism is not a design constraint.

Depending on the performance you need, and the particular OS, either Cortex-M or Cortex-R might be suitable for your application.One key point to check is the memory-management requirements of the OS (MMU or MPU).

Answer (score 0):

The Cortex-R series is specifically intended for real-time applications:

> The Arm Cortex-R real-time processors offer high-performance computing solutions for embedded systems where reliability, high availability, fault tolerance and/or deterministic real-time responses are needed. Cortex-R processors are used in products where performance requirements and timing deadlines must always be met.

-- [ARM's Cortex-R marketing page](https://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-r)

Cortex-A and Cortex-M cores can also be used in real-time applications, but may have less consistent performance.

Comment: So what is the performance difference between the cortices if I use A series instead of R for running RTOS?